# X-Robots-Tag - Noindex several files in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, server-side, web-development-server

I found on Google that I can noindex/nofollow using the X-Robots-Tag. There are plenty of webpages where they tell me how to do that on single files, entire websites, and directories. This is the way I’m supposed to do it for a single file:

```
    <FilesMatch "robots.txt">
    Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex"
    </FilesMatch>
```

But I need to noindex more than one file in a website and have’t been able to figure out how to do it. I have searched in Google and stackoverflow, but haven’t found the answer yet. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: The manual for `FilesMatch` has an example already, how to match multiple different file suffixes. Using `|` to specify alternatives in regex syntax is the main part here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me several weeks to give in trying to use a three-directory-deep path in order to noindex some files in `.htaccess`. I was Goggling for that long trying to figure out what to do, and finally found out that you just have to use the file name without the path and `Apache` applies the rule to any file in the file system with the provided file name. So this is what I finally did, which I think did the trick for me:

```
# Prevent search engines from indexing some files
<FilesMatch "^(about-cosma.html|footer.html|menu.html|acerca-de-cosma.html|es-footer.html|es-menu.html)">
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</FilesMatch>
```

This article helped me. https://gist.github.com/ankurk91/ee339291c6666dcba794